# How to do facet search with Pysolr

Tags: python, solr, pysolr

when we use curl or urlopen with facet to execute queries, we get a nested dictionary with 3 elements
1. responseHeader 2. response 3. facet_counts

I want to show the facet_counts while using Pysolr search. It just shows the 'response' value of the query output. I'm trying the following code, please help.

```
import pysolr
conn = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/')
result = conn.search('enron', **{
    'fl' : 'body',
    'facet' : 'on'
})   
for r in result:
    print r
```

Comment: You're not requesting any facets - you'll need at least one `facet.field` as well.

Comment: adding { 'facet' : 'to' } still does not change anything

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say - you need to request at least one `facet.field`. Set `'facet': 'true', 'facet.field': '<name of field in index>'`.

Comment: It is still giving the same output as before, adding 'facet.field' is not showing the facets in the search. even in the original code, it should return an empty dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're iterating over the `result` variable, you're iterating over pysolr's own [Results object](https://github.com/django-haystack/pysolr/blob/master/pysolr.py#L228) (and not directly over the JSON structure as shown by Solr).

```
import pysolr
import pprint

conn = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8080/solr/corename')
result = conn.search('*:*', **{
    'fl': 'content',
    'facet': 'true',
    'facet.field': 'field_name'
})   

pprint.pprint(result.facets)
```

Any facets will be present under the `facets` property of this results object.

The example above outputs:

```
{'facet_dates': {},
 'facet_fields': {'field_name': ['value', 54439, 'value2', 21179]},
 'facet_intervals': {},
 'facet_queries': {},
 'facet_ranges': {}}
```